# CSS files property:value vs property: value (whitespace)

Tags: css, whitespace, conventions

According to W3Schools, saying `property: value` is not as correct as saying `property:value`.  While both ways work fine and it probably doesn't matter, I was wondering if one way is preferred over the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this isn't something to worry about and you'll see both, probably even mixed. I personally use `property: value` but it is entirely in the vain of cleaner, more readable code. I would say that you should be careful in taking everything you read from W3Schools to heart. There are definitely people who [disagree](http://www.w3fools.com/) with them on a lot of things.